# Is there an advantage in using Static Class over Properties.Settings to hold constants?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

If I want to define a set of global strings in my C# program, I've been using settings so that I access them with

```
    ... Properties.Settings.Default.StringA ...
    ... Properties.Settings.Default.StringB ...
```

etc.

I was reading some SO questions that landed me with the idea I should create a static class

```
    public static class Marker
    {
         public static readonly string StringA = "my text A";
         public static readonly string StringB = "my_other_text";
    }
```

of course, accessing these would be simple with

```
      Marker.StringA
```

While I'm developing my hadbits, which method should I use for what constants or is this a personal style choice?

Thanks.

Comment: Are these meant to be user visible text? If so, you should be using a resource manager...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724025/in-c-whats-the-best-way-to-store-a-group-of-constants-that-my-program-uses

Comment: @Habib - thanks!  Clearly, I wasn't asking the question the right way in the search !

Comment: @Habib - In your reading of Q 1724025 that you referenced, is the consensus that if your program is a small standalone and not part of a larger project, that static classes are fine?

Comment: One thing about static classes is that if the strings change, you will have to recompile and consequently retest the class.  With your properties, they can be changed in a configuration file without recompiling the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the resource manager for access to culture-specific resources at run time. Etc text displayed on UI.
2. Use the App.Config or Web.Config for environment based constants. Here is a good example from Skeet https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431754/208565
3. Use constants and readonly fields for code level usage.

Answer (score 0):

Since all configuration files are cached by default this is just a matter of personal preference.

[**Is reading app.config expensive?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9569262/284240)